# "I hope it will be going well or I hope it will go well?"

Tags: future

Can I say "I hope it will be going well?"
My friend's going to an interview tomorrow

Thanks everyone

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You would say "I hope it goes well" in this instance.

Comment: I agree that the length of your answer is justified but there should be an explanation of why it fits. Also, for suggestions, we use the comments secrion.